# Infinite loop when redirecting in getInitialProps in Next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, infinite-loop

I have just learn Next.js and I have one problem with `getInitialProps` in `_app.jsx`.
I don't know why have an infinite loop error.
Please tell me why infinite loop and how to fix it.

```js
const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {

  return (
    <>
       <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  console.log("run 1");
  if (ctx.res) {
    console.log("run here");
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
      Location: "/login",
    });
    ctx.res.end();
  }
  return {};
};

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: The infinite loop happens because that code will also run when you're on the `/login` page.

Comment: thanks you, but if i don't use  ctx.res?.writeHead(302, { Location: "/login"}); in getInitialProps just log 1 times, u know why that?

Answer (score 2):

The infinite loop happens because the redirect also happens when you're on the `/login` page. To prevent it, make sure no redirection happens when you're on that page.

```js
MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
    if (ctx.res && ctx.asPath !== "/login") {
        ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
            Location: "/login",
        });
        ctx.res.end();
     }
     return {};
};
```

Comment: Fairly sure this is the right answer, in addition I am wondering if a 302 is needed, you can simply do a   `redirect(ctx, /login);`